# Antlr4 supports cross linking in a grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to write a grammar for a state transition language using Antlr4

This system has variables (e.g., states) that are declared once and can be referenced elsewhere.

My question is: **does Antlr4 support cross-references as in [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#cross_reference)**?

If Antlr4 does not provide this functionality, I guess an "easy" way to do it is by having a memory Map that parses the tokens and stores the information in this Map?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, cross-references in XText can implement a degree of complexity that would be hard to duplicate outside of an EMF-based system.

However, in its simplest form, cross-references require little more than a static symbol table. Depending on your needs, [symbol versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588452/build-symbol-table-from-grammar-antlr/15602385#15602385) based on state traversal may be adequate.  Versioning would be normally performed during a tree walk.  Initialization of static symbols could be performed in grammar-based actions, though likely best done in the parser rather than the lexer.