# Generating symbol table using Antlr4

Tags: antlr4, symbol-table

I am learning how to generate a symbol table using Antlr4. I came across [this](https://github.com/parrt/cs652/tree/master/lectures/code/symtab/src) example (and the only one so far) but it gives compilation errors for the files generated by Antlr4.

(commands: 
`antlr4 Simple.g4` and `javac Simple*.java`)

```
-bash-4.1$ javac Simple*.java
SimpleBaseListener.java:3: error: package org.antlr.symbols does not exist
import org.antlr.symbols.*;
^
SimpleListener.java:3: error: package org.antlr.symbols does not exist
import org.antlr.symbols.*;
^
SimpleParser.java:3: error: package org.antlr.symbols does not exist
import org.antlr.symbols.*;
^
SimpleParser.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
            public Scope scope;
                   ^
symbol:   class Scope
location: class FileContext
SimpleParser.java:166: error: cannot find symbol
            public Scope scope;
                   ^
symbol:   class Scope
location: class FuncContext
SimpleParser.java:356: error: cannot find symbol
            public Scope scope;
                   ^
symbol:   class Scope
location: class BlockContext
SimpleLexer.java:3: error: package org.antlr.symbols does not exist
import org.antlr.symbols.*;
^
7 errors
```

My guess is that this implementation uses an old verison of Antlr.

Is there an example for Antlr4? I tried the official [documentation](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/) but it is not very helpful for a newbie.

Comment: Try [https://github.com/antlr/symtab](https://github.com/antlr/symtab)

Comment: @GRosenberg isn't this built using Antlr3 (or 2) and not Antlr4? Antlr4 is very different from its previous versions, so many of the features in Antlr3 and below don't work for Antlr4

Comment: No. It is for Antlr4.  This earlier answer provides a [symbol table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588452/build-symbol-table-from-grammar/15602385#15602385) for a more general language use.